# Getting the PC value in ARM assembly

Tags: windows-mobile, assembly, arm

I have a Windows Mobile 6 ARMV4I project where I would like to get the value of the program counter.

The function is declared like this:

```
extern "C" unsigned __int32 GetPC();
```

My assembly code looks like this:

```
GetPC FUNCTION
    EXPORT GetPC
    ldr r0, [r15]   ; load the PC value in to r0
    mov pc, lr      ; return the value of r0
ENDFUNC
```

But, when I call the `GetPC()` function, I get the same number every time. So, I'm assuming my assembly isn't doing what I think it's doing. Can anybody point out what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PC is same every time, because  `ldr r0, [r15]` has fixed address (PC is always same there). use R14 because it holds return address, that might be what you need. or use inline functions.

Comment: Assuming he's using Microsoft tools, inline ARM assembler isn't supported.

Comment: This is my first foray in to assembly, so I'm probably misunderstanding you. But, R15 is the program counter and R0 is the return value according to http://www.pentest.co.uk/documents/exploringwce/exploring_wce_shellcode.html#N10081. Are you saying that site is wrong and it's actually R14? Thanks

Comment: @ctacke - Yes, I'm using VS2008 and inline `__arm` commands aren't supported.

Comment: @PaulH every instruction has address. once function is compiled, it's instructions are put into memory and have fixed address. when you do ldr r0, [r15] you will have same result, because this instruction is pinned into memory. you can try macros if they are supported.

Comment: @PaulH what is your arm assembler compiler?

Comment: @Andrey - ARMASM.exe v15.00.20720. It comes with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

Comment: try: extern inline "C" unsigned __int32 GetPC();

Answer (score 4):

If this is a true function, you should always get the same value in this code since you're just returning the current PC which is inside GetPC.

You probably want:

```
move r0, lr // put return address in r0
move pc, lr // return
```